# Is there an official notation used to designate entire equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, notation

When showing my work on really any type of math problem, but mostly Algebra, I like to use = to show my steps, especially when typing work up on the computer. For example, `(x+y=z) = (x=z-y)`. But, this gets confusing when using lots of parenthesis, especially on a computer or program where math formatting doesn't exist. So my question is: Is there an official notation used to designate entire equations or formulas? Like:`[x+y=z] = [x=z-y]`, or `<x+y=z> = <x=z-y>`. Thank you!

Comment: You can use $$x+y=z\iff y=z-x$$ in the case the equations are equivalent